# powershell Foreach-Object

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

I have this array (simplyfied):

```
$v = 3,5,3,6,8,3,5,7
```

I need to check if all the values are higher than 3. I think that Foreach or Foreach-Object will be suitable for this task, but I can't figure out the way it works.

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work.

```
$v | Foreach-Object (if($_ -lt 10){Write-Host "$_ lt 10"})
```

**EDIT:**

Thank you, guys!
I changed the statement to:

```
$v | Foreach-Object {if($_ -lt 10){$check_value = "True"}}
```

It's working now, but I just realized, that the simplyfied array wasn't a good idea. The data in array I'm using are grabbed from MS SQL database. If I display the array on screen, I get numbers, but the type of data is System.Data.DataRow, which I can not compare to number. I get error msg:

```
Bad argument to operator '-lt': Could not compare "System.Data.DataRow" to "95". Error: "Cannot convert the "95" value of type "System.Int32" to type "System.Data.DataRow".".
```

**EDIT2:**

splatteredbits:

I'm using your code, everything works fine, but I cannot pass through this comparison:

```
$rowsGreaterThanThree.Count -eq $v.Count
```

the values of $rowsGreaterThanThree are:

### ProcessorTime

0.00127998361620918
1.53972183002211
0.00127998361620918
0.00127998361620918
0.00127998361620918
1.53972183002211
0.00127998361620918
0.00127998361620918
0.00127998361620918
3.1262399841282
0
0
0
0
0

and $v contains:

### ProcessorTime

0.00127998361620918
1.53972183002211
0.00127998361620918
0.00127998361620918
0.00127998361620918
1.53972183002211
0.00127998361620918
0.00127998361620918
0.00127998361620918
3.1262399841282
0
0
0
0
0

The values are the same, but there is one more blank row in $v beneath the "ProcessorTime"(here it's not visible). Count gives 16 instead of 15 in $rowsGreaterThanThree.Count.

My code: (I modyfied -gt to -ge, because there are zeros. In working version I want to check if processor is loaded above 95% for a time period.)

```
$warning_values = @( $check | Where-Object { $_.ProcessorTime -ge 0 } )
if($warning_values.Count -eq $check.Count )
    {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor "Warning!"
        }
        else { Write-Host "nothing"}
```

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that you need to wrap the foreach statement in brackets {} instead of parens.

Comment: Haha, anyone got there because the misleading blogs as close as to 23 JANUARY 2020, like [this one](https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-foreach/)?

Answer (score 5):

Simple :)

```
PS> $v -gt 3
5
6
8
5
7
```

Or

```
$v | Where-Object { $_ -gt 3 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Shay's example is perfect: use `Where-Object` to filter items from an array.

Because your objects are [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx) objects, you'll need to filter on the column:

```
$rowsGreaterThanThree = @( $v | Where-Object { $_.ColumnName -gt 3 } )
if( $rowsGreaterThanThree.Count -eq $v.Count )
{
  Write-Host "All the rows are greater than 3!"
}
```

Replace `ColumnName` with the name of the column which contains the actual value you want to filter on.

You can also do this in SQL with a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column > 3
```

Then, you're getting just the values you want out of SQL Server.  Of course, you may need the unfiltered values in your script, too.

Comment: This gets the > 3 values, but you should add how to check his actual question - how to determine *if all are > 3*.  Need to wrap the query in `@()` and check `.Count`, might not be obvious to a powershell newbie :)

Comment: @latkin Thanks.  I didn't read carefully.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, splattered bits. As I mentioned above, I want to check processor time for a time period, and when it's load is above 95%, I want to do some action. Therefore I think that I need all the data from database (e.g. last 20 rows) and recognize, if the load is above 95% in every single value. I don't know how to get last 20 rows yet, but it's another question;)